# SQL - Codeigniter - Retorna apenas um registro

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Senhores, tenho a seguinte função:

```
// Busca Simples
public function buscando(){

    // pesquisar_palavra, idCategoria, idSubCategoria       

        if($this->input->post('pesquisar_palavra')){ 
            $this->db->like('noticia.titulo', $this->input->post('pesquisar_palavra')); 
        }   
        if($this->input->post('idCategoria')){ 
            $this->db->select('noticia.*, categoria.categoria');
            $this->db->join('categoria', "categoria.id=noticia.id"); 
            $this->db->where('categoria.id', $this->input->post('idCategoria'));
        }
        if($this->input->post('idSubCategoria')){ 
            $this->db->where('noticia.id_categoria', $this->input->post('idSubCategoria')); 
        }

    $this->db->where('noticia.ativo', 1);
    $this->db->order_by('noticia.data', 'DESC');
    $this->db->order_by('noticia.id', 'DESC');
    $consulta = $this->db->get('noticia')->result();

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($consulta);
    echo "</pre>";
    die();
}
```

O retorno dele é apenas um registro, e não 3, como mostra o banco de dados a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é o critério do Post de Pesquisar.

```
Array
(
    [pesquisar_palavra] => 
    [idCategoria] => 1
    [idSubCategoria] => 5
)
```

Comment: Oi, poderia dar mais informações a respeita do problema, como a estrutra das tabelas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Troque a linha:

```
$consulta = $this->db->get('noticia')->result();
```

Por:

```
$consulta = $this->db->get('noticia');
```